# search all nodes within particular radius with latitude and longitude in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

suppose users' geolocation is on. Based on current location (lat/long) he/ she gives the request to get all nodes between 0 to 100 km how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Neo4j 3.4.x we introduced spatial data types, and indexing of spatial properties.

You should review the sections in the documentation on [spatial types](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/spatial/#cypher-spatial-index) and [spatial functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/spatial/).

Let's assume you're using the WGS-84 coordinate reference system (CRS) for saving longitude/latitude coordinates as point properties on nodes.

An example of setting a point property on a node:

```
CREATE (l:Location {coords:point({ longitude: 56.7, latitude: 12.78 })})
```

You should have an index on :Location(coords) to be able to [leverage the index for quick lookups by distance radius](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/indexes/#administration-indexes-spatial-distance-searches-single-property-index).

An example, provided $longitude and $latitude and $radius inputs, for finding all :Locations within a given $radiusKM:

```
MATCH (l:Location)
WHERE distance(l.coords, point({longitude:$longitude, latitude:$latitude})) <= $radiusKM * 1000
RETURN l
```